# Check if NSDictionary is Null?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've tried multiple ways. I know the dictionary is NULL, as the console also prints out  when I break there. Yet when I put it in an if(  ) it doesn't trigger.

```
([myDict count] == 0) //results in crash
(myDict == NULL)
[myDict isEqual:[NSNull null]]
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail? It's pretty bad if you're getting `NULL` for your `NSDictionary`, as opposed to the usual `nil` (for which `[myDict count] == 0` should be fine).

Comment: Don't merely describe what your console says; provide a dump of what you see in the console.

Comment: @JeremyRoman if myDict is `nil` then `[myDict count]` will cause an  `NSInvalidArgumentException` exception.

Comment: Then `myDict` isn't `nil`. Passing a message to `nil` should not result in a crash. Could it be that `myDict` is a invalid reference (for example, a reference to a freed object)?

Comment: If you "NSLog("myDict: <%@>", myDict);" what is output? If that crashes then myDict isn't pointing to a valid ObjC object (ether bogus pointer or released object).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It looks like you have a dangling or wild pointer.

You can consider Objective-C objects as pointers to structs.

You can then of course compare them with `NULL`, or with other pointers.

So:

```
( myDict == NULL )
```

and

```
( myDict == [ NSNull null ] )
```

are both valid.

The first one will check if the pointer is `NULL`. `NULL` is usually defined as a `void *` with a value of 0.
Note that, for Objective-C objects, we usually use `nil`. `nil` is also defined as a `void *` with a value of 0, so it equals `NULL`. It's just here to denote a `NULL` pointer to an object, rather than a standard pointer.

The second one compares the address of `myDict` with the singleton instance of the `NSNull` class. So you are here comparing two pointers values.

So to quickly resume:

```
NULL == nil == Nil == 0
```

And as `[ NSNull null ]` is a valid instance:

```
NULL != [ NSNull null ]
```

Now about this:

```
( [ myDict count ] == 0 )
```

It may crash if you have a wild pointer:

```
NSDictionary * myDict;

[ myDict count ];
```

Unless using ARC, it will surely crash, because the `myDict` variable has not been initialised, and may actually point to anything.

It may also crash if you have a dangling pointer:

```
NSDictionary * myDict;

myDict = [ [ NSDictionary alloc ] init ];

[ myDict release ];
[ myDict count ];
```

Then you'll try to send a message to a deallocated object.
Sending a message to `nil`/`NULL` is always valid in Objective-C.

So it depends if you want to check if a dictionary is `nil`, or if it doesn't have values (as a valid dictionary instance may be empty).

In the first case, compare with `nil`. Otherwise, checks if count is 0, and ensure you're instance is still valid. Maybe you just forgot a retain somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

```
if (TheDict == (NSDictionary*) [NSNull null]){

//TheDict is null
    }
else{
//TheDict is not null

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a dictionary has nil or NULL data, you can check for the [dictionary count] which will return 0 in all cases

Answer (score 0):

All above doesn't work for me but this

```
if([mydict isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
{
   NSLog("Dic is Null")
}
else
{
   NSLog("Dic is Not Null")  
}
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
if([NSNull null] != [serverResponseObject objectForKey:@"Your_Key"])
{
//Success
}
```

Comment: Could you include some explanation how this solves the problem?