# Check if contain Null

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I print the following I get `(null)`

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[responseObject objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"child"]);
```

Now I want to do a validation to check if it returns `(null)`. How am I supposed to do this?

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

1.

```
 if (![[[responseObject objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"child"] isEqualToString:@"(null)"]) {

}
```

2.

```
if (![[[responseObject objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"child"]  isEqual:@"(null)"]) {
}
```

Comment: did you try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960209/check-if-nsdictionary-is-null?

Answer (score 2):

"null" isn't just a `NSString`. You should do some research into the concept of a null object.

What you're looking for can be written like this:

```
if (![[responseObject objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"child"]) {
    //key "child" not in dictionary
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`(null)` is the representation of `nil` displayed by `NSLog`.

You can write the following:

```
if ([[responseObject objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"child"] == nil) {

}
```

Or a shorter alternative:

```
if (![[responseObject objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"child"]) {

}
```

Comment: This is a great answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check is to use string length. I know other answers are just as good, I am just giving OP and anyone else in future some more options.

```
NSString *childStr = [[responseObject objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"child"];

if ([childStr length] < 1)
{
  //no value specified - childStr is NULL
}
else
{ 
 //there is something in the childStr - throw a party!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"hello"]) {
  NSLog(@"only if not null show %@",[defaults objectForKey:@"hello"]);
}
```

This is a way to check it from User Defaults. It will only print if the saved object does not equal `null`.